Blender theme, How to float the panels on the left and right
I found a theme which is influenced by Cinema 4D. I'm altering some parts of the theme to better suite my custom workspace/Theme. I want to float the tool panel on the left and the panels on the right, like Blender's custom theme. I can't find where in the Preference section this is located.



Unless you code it, the only way to have a floating panel is to create and resize a whole new window, but I don't think it's a handy workaround for your purposes.


Thanks for your reply Josh. I should be more specific. Blender's default panels are on the left and right, but have the grid expanding to the boundary of the viewport. The theme I have downloaded, has the grid cut off like a square shape.
https://ibb.co/fn4HZKQ

Maybe those panels have opacity settings to make the grid appear behind them.

This was answered on another forum, and I solved my problem.
https://ibb.co/wKKCFc3
